# PowerShell loop do until ($inifinity) with timer

Tags: powershell, timer

I have the following loop that executes a series of vbs scripts; I would like to add a  MsgBox to display how long did the loop take to execute. For the purpose of posting I only listed 5 of the 200 scripts that the loop iterates over.

```
do
{
   cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting1.vbs
   cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting2.vbs
   cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting3.vbs
   cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting4.vbs
   cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting5.vbs
   start-sleep -Seconds 400
}
until ($infinity)
```

Comment: I used the wrong tag; the loop is executed in PowerShell not Python.

Comment: Throwing a dialog/msgbox si not a really automated way to do this, as one must be in front of the PC to dismiss the box before anything else would occur. It woudl be more prudent, just to let it default write to the screen that you can view as needed, or write to a log file to review later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my version of recording the runtime of do until by using StartNew() method. Starting a session when the loop starts then stops when the loop terminates and prints how many seconds it ran.

```
$stopwatch =  [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

do
{
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting1.vbs
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting2.vbs
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting3.vbs
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting4.vbs
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting5.vbs
    start-sleep -Seconds 400
}until ($infinity)

$stopwatch.Stop()
$stopwatch
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$t1 = New-TimeSpan -End (Get-Date -DisplayHint Time)
do 
{
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting1.vbs 
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting2.vbs 
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting3.vbs 
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting4.vbs 
    cscript c:\MyFiles\MyScripts\sorting5.vbs 
    start-sleep -Seconds 400 
} until ($infinity)
$t2 = New-Timespan -End (Get-Date -DisplayHint Time)
$interval = $t2 - $t1
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$interval = $interval.TotalSeconds
$WshShell.PopUp("$($interval) seconds needed to complete the task.")
```

Comment: i think wshshell is excess here ---
$WshShell.PopUp("$($interval) seconds needed to complete the task.")

Comment: but its usefull, thats how we know new things, like me for example